# Laravel Socialite throws ClientException or InvalidStateException only in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have for the last 8 hours tried to fix a login problem with Laravel Socialite that only accurs when i'm on production server (Ubuntu 16 and LEMP stack). The login with Socialite works on localhost. I'm using Laravel 5.5 and Socialite 3.0.

The problem is when Facebook redirects back with the code and state params and Socialite tries to get the token. The url below gives the 500 error..

```
https://website.com/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQA-KiBJG3Ge_3DqktPGjpjrqIbmOy2Q4f6nW...&state=V9uOnjYU6cOHu0rbs...
```

**Controller:**

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{

    return Socialite::driver($provider)->scopes(['user_birthday', 'user_work_history', 'user_education_history'])->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{

    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user(); //Where error is thrown

    session()->put('fb_token', $user->token);

}
```

Using the handler with `Socialite::driver($provider)->user();` throws..

```
    (1/1) InvalidStateException
    in AbstractProvider.php (line 209)
    at AbstractProvider->user()
    in LoginController.php (line 65)
    at LoginController->handleProviderCallback('facebook')
    ...
```

When I change the handler to `Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();` it throws

```
(1/1) ClientException
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"Missing authorization code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"hghkl145"}}
in RequestException.php (line 113)
at RequestException::create(object(Request), object(Response))
in Middleware.php (line 65)
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Response))
in Promise.php (line 203)
at Promise::callHandler(1, object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null))
in Promise.php (line 156)
...
```

It feels like I have tried everything from the forums like SERVICE_DOMAIN in services.php, ngix settings, stateless(), clear cache, doublecheck facebook panel setting, .env file etc but it won't work..

Comment: Check you have entered the correct call back URL in the environment file and your facebook account. It works on localhost because you have entered the correct URL's but when on production your URL's are getting changed and facebook unable to redirect to your localhost URL.

Comment: @Suraj I doubled checked again. It's the same in env file and and valid redirects in facebook